# Matlab set() figure title raises exception

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm writing a function which ought to plot to an already created axes. The function provides the option to re-title the axes, and I'm trying to make that functionality work.

If the axes doesn't already have a title then just calling title() works, of course.

But: If the axes does already have a title, then calling title() overprints the original title, but leaves the original in place.

So: I've been experimenting with set():

```
T_old = get(gca, 'Title');
T_new = set(T_old, 'String', 'New Title');
```

Which leaves me the error message:

```
One or more output arguments not assigned during call to "set".
```

What am I doing wrong? Are there other arguments which must be set for the Title handle? And if so what?

Comment: `title` does not normally overprint the previous title, but replaces it. If in your case that's different, you must have an unusual setup, e.g. two overlaid axes. As a matter of fact, `title.m` essentially does `h = get(ax,'Title'); set(h, 'String', string);` (lines 42 and 55).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set does not have any output arguments, thus call `set(T_old, 'String', 'New Title');` without any return variables.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I'd already confirmed that as correct! I'll blame the crappy internet at work. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

From the help for `set`:

> A = set(H, 'PropertyName')
>       set(H,'PropertyName')
>       returns or displays the possible values for the specified property of 
>       the object with handle H.  The returned array is a cell array of 
>       possible value strings or an empty cell array if the property does not 
>       have a finite set of possible string values.

However, you're calling `set` and and actually setting a property value. This is not a valid input pattern. Just call this instead:

```
set(T_old, 'String', 'New Title');
```